# What is core.js and where is it?

Tags: support, javascript, winter-bash-2014

In every single question about "How many secret hats are there", there's this sentence which I don't understand...

> ...according to **core.js**, there are 8 secret hats and...

What exactly is **core.js**, where do you find it, why does it tell you, and how does it tell you? (i.e. What is it)

Comment: This is a JavaScript file, JavaScript being programming  language used to make HTML pages dynamic. The hats are using lots of JavaScript, so people were able to "decipher" part of the logic since JS is client side and available to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [@Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245250/what-is-core-js-and-where-is-it#comment802679_245250) mentioned in the comments, core.js is simply a JavaScript file.

It can be found here http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/core.js

It helps make the awesomeness that is hats a reality!